# UIActionSheet positioning issue within ScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to display an `ActionSheet` when a screen is touched within `scrollview`. The action sheet pops fine within the first page.  But on subsequent pages the screen becomes dark and doesn't displaying anything, as if actual button is displaying on the off screen.  I have tested different frame positioning of `UIActionSheet` but it does not seem to work.

**self.view.frame.origin.x** seems to have correct ScrollView  position.

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                                  initWithTitle:nil 
                                  delegate:self 
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Jump to First Page", @"Browse Pages",nil];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, 480.0f, 320.0f);  
[actionSheet setFrame:frame];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `UIScrollView` is contained in the `view` of a `UIViewController`.

You should then display that `UIActionSheet` inside the root view of the view controller.

Comment: thanks I ended up using *UIWindow as ScrollView's root controller's root view was UIWindow... Now, my app is in Landscape mode.  All my ScrollView is displaying in Landscape mode.(I did ShouldAutoRotate... & Transformation) but UIActionSheet shows in Portrait... Any Idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is because the `UIWindow` does not rotate. Only `UIViewControllers` do. (Where 'rotate' really is applying a transformation to change the coordinate system)

Answer (score -1):

You are displaying it inside the scrollview, which will not work, because you are right, it is displayed off screen. you shouldn't display it inside the scrollview, rather, put the Scrollview in another view and display the ActionSheet inside that view.

Comment: thanks I ended up using *UIWindow as ScrollView's root controller's root view was UIWindow... Now, my app is in Landscape mode.  All my ScrollView is displaying in Landscape mode.(I did ShouldAutoRotate... & Transformation) but UIActionSheet shows in Portrait... Any Idea? Thanks in advance!